# Flex 4 Scroller sometimes doesn't show

Tags: apache-flex, scroll, scroller

Ok so I have a simple unskinned Scroller component , the problem I'm having is that at aparently random times the vertical scrollbar dissapears. 
I can still scroll the content with my mouse wheel but you can understand how that's just not enough for a quality product.

here's my code

```
<s:Scroller id="scroller" width="100%" height="150" horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="on">
    <s:DataGroup
        dataProvider            = "{_myDataSource}"
        width                   = "100%"

        clipAndEnableScrolling  = "true"
        itemRenderer            = "MyItemRenderer"> 
        <s:layout>
            <s:VerticalLayout
                useVirtualLayout    = "true"
                rowHeight           = "30"
                gap                 = "10" 
                horizontalAlign     = "left" 
                paddingRight        = "10"
                verticalAlign       = "top"/>
        </s:layout>
    </s:DataGroup>
</s:Scroller>
```

Is it a flex bug? 
As I've said it seems to happen randomly. 
The only thing I do know is that it only triggers when and if the data source array gets changed. For instance in a chat window where messages keep comming in.
This occurred for me in multiple places so I'm thinking it's not the ItemRenderer that's causing the problem.

Comment: Nothing looks wrong.  Can you show us a full runnable sample that illustrates the problem?  You'll need to include a dataProvider for that.  Also specify which version of the Flex SDK you are using.

Comment: Hey. You may be better off setting the height of the scroller to 100%, and placing the scroller inside a component of height 150. I had issues with something like that before

Answer (score 1):

Setting the height of the scroller to 100%, and placing the scroller inside a component of height 150 ,Still, it seems "100%" should work